# ASP.NET API как брать данные из базы данных PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net, rest

Решил разработать API сервер и столкнулся с проблемой, ни в каких источниках не рассказывают как сделать взаимодействие с PostgreSQL, может это я тупой и чего то не понимаю. Очень надо, поставьте меня на правильный путь в этом API на ASP.NET

Comment: От версии фреймворка зависит, но начать читать можно тут https://metanit.com/sharp/efcore/7.3.php

Comment: Try install Npgsql nuget-package